# Measure and label length on an image

Tags: image, image-processing

I am looking for the easiest way to draw a solid line on a picture and display the length of the line drawn. Attached a picture. Any idea to do it under win7?
Thank you

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3U7Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to go to [ImageJ](https://ij.imjoy.io/) in your browser, and click:

```
File -> Open Sample -> Cardio
```

Then click `Line Tool` and draw your line. It'll tell you the length in the info window.

You could equally install it locally, but that would be harder.

You could just as easily use [Photopea](https://www.photopea.com/).

Answer (score -1):

To draw a line coordinates are needed. So then it's possible to calculate the length of the line from equation: length = sqrt((Xend - Xstart)^2 + (Yend - Ystart)^2 ). And according to that example mentioned in question: You can make a loop for every row to store the value of first coloured pixel and last coloured pixel, calculate the length between them and compare the result with the next row. In auxiliary variable may be stored the maximal result (actualization after every row calculation)

```
// C++ Implementation for drawing line
#include <graphics.h>
  
// driver code
int main()
{
    // gm is Graphics mode which is a computer display
    // mode that generates image using pixels.
    // DETECT is a macro defined in "graphics.h" header file
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
  
    // initgraph initializes the graphics system
    // by loading a graphics driver from disk
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
  
    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2
    line(150, 150, 450, 150);
  
    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2
    line(150, 200, 450, 200);
  
    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2
    line(150, 250, 450, 250);
  
    getch();
  
    // closegraph function closes the graphics
    // mode and deallocates all memory allocated
    // by graphics system .
    closegraph();
}
```

You can use C++ for example CodeBlocks. But to start the best would be Processing https://processing.org/reference/line_.html

Comment: Do you know any software already has this function?

Comment: Downloading Processing is the easiest way to do that in my opinion - take a look for a link

Comment: seriously? *processing*? for calculating the length of a line between points with known coordinates? you can "pick" coordinates using any image editor. you can even do it with OpenCV. imshow the picture, set a mouse callback, collect positions when mouse button is clicked.

Comment: Yes @ChristophRackwitz it's possible even with MSPAINT but Processing may be a good start to a programming world